# Load a javascript file when i select an option in popup.html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

im making a chrome extension and i have a problem loading a file...
I want to load a file when i select an option in the `popup.html` file
for example, if i select `option1` i want `eventPage1.js`, to be loaded, and if i select `option2` i want `eventPage2.js` to be loaded, but not the two at the same time, just one.

This its my popup.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form>
Paises en el menu contextual:
<br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="opcion1" name="opcion" value="opcion1" onclick= <script src="eventPage1.js"></script>
    <label for="opcion1">Todos los paises</label>

    <input type="radio" id="opcion2" name="opcion" value="opcion2" onclick= <script src="eventPage2.js"></script>
    <label for="opcion2">Solo Mexico</label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

each eventpage file, its a context menu...

this its how my manifest file looks like

```js
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "help me",
"author": "me man",
"version": "1.1.4",
"description": "test test",
"browser_action":
 {
  "default_icon": "icon-large.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
  
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["menuSelection.js"]
 }, 
  "permissions": [
 "storage",
 "contextMenus"
  ],
  "icons": {
          "16": "icon-bitty.png",
          "48": "icon-small.png",
          "128": "icon-large.png"
 }
}
```

another problem that i have, its that when i select an option... save that option in storage so everytime i use the extension its automatically loaded that option

Comment: Your question is **unclear** to me. Are you asking us to write this for you? To debug some code you've written, but that you have not provided? It also appears to be too broad as you have tacked on some extra requirements at the end. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are wanting. Note that SO is not, in general, a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Event page* is a technical term for the page declared in `"background"` section of manifest.json with `"persistent": false`. It's not just a name. It's a special context which exists only for that single hidden page. Make sure to read the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).
2. Inline code in html file doesn't work in extension pages by default for security reasons (the `onclick` attribute in your html). Handle all events in a separate js file
3. The `input` tags in your html aren't closed, and actually malformed. There's no opening `<body>`.
4. To save the options use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API or the old primitive string-based `localStorage`
5. To dynamically load js files, add a `script` element dynamically into `head` with its `src` property set to the name of the file to load. Or use the modern [require()](https://github.com/letorbi/smoothie/blob/master/standalone/require.js)-based approach. However, you might want to start learning using a single script file.
6. Don't use `form`: the browser is not a web server so the page cannot be submitted. It will simply reload and you'll lose all data. Of course you can prevent the `submit` event in a listener but it defeats the purpose of using a `form`. Instead process a change immediately.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Paises en el menu contextual:
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="opcion" value="opcion1">Todos los paises</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="opcion" value="opcion2">Solo Mexico</label>
  </div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
function setRadio(name, value) {
  const el = document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"][value="${value}"]`);
  if (el && !el.checked) {
    el.checked = true;
  }
}

chrome.storage.sync.get('opcion', data => {
  setRadio('opcion', data.opcion);
});

document.onchange = event => {
  if (event.target.name == 'opcion') {
    const value = event.target.value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({opcion: value});

    switch (value) {
      case 'opcion1':
        doSomething1();
        break;
      case 'opcion2':
        doSomething2();
        break;
    }
  }
};

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, area) => {
  if (area == 'sync' && 'opcion' in changes) {
    setRadio('opcion', changes.opcion.newValue);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you would probably want to do something like this when you click on the selected option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function LoadJavascriptFile(fileToLoad){  
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.id = "customScript";
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "fileToLoad"; 
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }


</script>
```

On you option select you'd call

```
LoadJavascriptFile("PathToMyFile.js")
```

You'd then check if the Script ID exists in the header.  If it does, update the SRC otherwise create the SRC